# Как правильно объявить глобальный массив в си?

Tags: c, массивы, объявление

У меня есть несколько массивов, которые хранят числа.

```
int bcint0 [2] = {0x66663C00, 0x3C6666};  
int bcint1 [2] = {0x3C1C0C00, 0xC0C0C};
...
```

Они нужны мне в нескольких разных файлах.
Как и где правильно их объявить, что бы к этим массивам был доступ из разных .с файлов программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

1. Создать `.c` файл с этими массивами:

```
int bcint0 [2] = {0x66663C00, 0x3C6666};  
int bcint1 [2] = {0x3C1C0C00, 0xC0C0C};
...
```

2. Создать `.h` файл, в который поместить `extern` обьявления этих массивов:

```
#ifndef HEADER_NAME_H_
#define HEADER_NAME_H_

extern int bcint0[];  
extern int bcint1[];
...

#endif HEADER_NAME_H_
```

3. Включать наш `.h` файл во все файлы, в которых нужен доступ к этим массивам:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myarrs.h"  // тот самый .h файл из п.2

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // Получаем доступ к массивам
        printf("%d\n", bcint0[i] + bcint1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало